# Proximal Operator for trace of the Hadamard product of matrix exponential

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I am new to proximal functions and I am currently stuck with the following problem:

How can I derive the proximal operator for this function: trace of the Hadamard product of an exponential matrix x

$$\text h(x)= tr(e^{x \circ\ x}) $$

The derivative of h(x):

$$\text h'(x)= (e^{x \circ\ x}) \circ\ 2x $$

Edit: I would like my proximal operator to be defined in terms of squared Euclidean distance (to a nonconvex closed set)
$$\text{d}(x)  =   \inf_{y\in C} \left\|x-y\right\|_2 $$
$$\text f(x)= \frac {d(x)^2 }{2}$$

$$\text prox_{\lambda f} (x)  =   \frac {1 }{1+\lambda} x + \frac {\lambda }{1+\lambda} P_C(x) $$

I would appreciate some help to derive the proximal operator if it can be done analytically.

I have reviewed https://archive.siam.org/books/mo25/mo25_ch6.pdf and also http://proximity-operator.net/multivariatefunctions.html.

The prox is defined to be

$$\mbox{prox}_f(x) = \arg\min_{y}f(x) + \frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$

Comment: can you give a definition of a proximal operator?

Comment: hi, i just made some new edits on definition of a proximal operator...thanks much

Comment: Start by calculating the subgradient.

Comment: Is $B$ function of x? How to interpret your function $h(x)$?

Comment: thks, i made changes to h(x)

Comment: I think you're mixing some things together here.Think what exactly is your function. You cannot cast your function as the distance function.